# Reset Search Results

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

Good morning. I made a data search & filter with datatables and it worked .. but when I moved the page and returned to that page the data was still stuck (not reset). In view I made it like the following image:

[image]

and in the js file I made it like this

```
brandmanage = $('#brandmanage').DataTable({
        dom : 'rtpi',
        pageLength:  {{ $limit ?? '10' }},
      language : {
        paginate : {
          previous : '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', // or '←' 
          next : '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', // or '→'
        },
      },
        processing : true,
        drawCallback : function( settings ) {
                $('#lengthInput option[value={{ $limit ?? '10' }}]').attr('selected','selected');
            },
        serverSide : true,
        stateSave : true,
        ajax : {
          url : "{{ route('lms.brand.getdata',['pfx'=>$pfx]) }}",
          dataType : "json",
          type : "POST",
          data : { _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" }
        },
        columns : [
          { data : "brand" },
          { data : "corporate" },
          { data : "num_of_company" },
          { data : "primary" },
          { data : "secondary" },
          { data : "status" },
          { data : "action",
            orderable : false,
            className : "text-center",
          },
        ],
      });


  $('#brandDataLength').on('change', function () {
        brandmanage.page.len( $(this).val() ).draw();
        });
        
  $('#searchBrand').on('keyup', function () {
    brandmanage.search( this.value ).draw();
    });
```

What do I do so that when I have moved pages, the search results can be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `stateSave` to false, then dataTables will not remember the selected filters etc. Thereby the search results will be reset when you reload the page.

Comment: Thank you very much @Per Henrik Lausten, it's been resolved. you are very helpful.

Comment: @HilmiHidayat great to hear. Please accept the answer as a correct answer. Thanks.